# Rails 4.x works in browser but fails Cucumber step

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber

I have a small business customer management app I'm working on.

My code seems to be working fine, but my cucumber test balks with the following message.

```
  And I have created one business      # features/step_definitions/owner_steps.rb:238
  No route matches {:action=>"new", :business_id=>nil, :controller=>"customers"} missing required keys: [:business_i
d] (ActionView::Template::Error)
  ./app/views/owners/show.html.erb:64:in `_app_views_owners_show_html_erb__1329160335005789747_57615300'
  ./features/step_definitions/owner_steps.rb:240:in `/^I have created one business$/'
  features/business_creates_customers.feature:9:in `And I have created one business'
```

Again, when I go to the page it works.   I believe the quirk is in how I'm going to the new_business_customers_path.   My "default" page is the owner show page.   And an owner has_many businesses.   But, the business has_many customers.   To get to the customer page and feed in the right business_id from the owner show page, I have a method to find the right business in the owner controller and it does correctly pass the parameters in the browser.

Anyway, here's my code:

**Owner (show.html.erb) -- note the new_business_customer_path(@business).  When I put @owner, @business, it feeds the OWNER id as the business_id**

```
<%= provide(:title, "#{@owner.name} Profile Page") %>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">

    <div class="panel panel-default">
        <div class="panel-heading">
        <b>Personal Information</b><%= link_to "Edit", '/edit', class: 'pull-right' %>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <b>Owner: </b>
        <%= link_to @owner.name, '/edit' %>
      <p>
        <b>Email: </b>
        <%= @owner.email %>
      </div>

      <% if @owner.businesses.count > 0 %>
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <b>Business Information</b><%= link_to "Add", new_owner_business_path(@owner), class: 'pull-right' %>
      </div>      
      <div class="panel-body">
        <% @owner.businesses.order("created_at asc").each do |business| %>
          <b>View:</b>
          <%= link_to business.name, owner_business_path(@owner, business) %><br>
        <% end %>
      </div>
      <% end %>

      </div>
  </div>

    <div class="col-md-10">
  <% if @owner.businesses.count == 0 %>
    <div class="panel panel-danger">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <b>Business Information</b>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>Thank you for signing up.   We will need information about your business for you to proceed.</p>
        <p>You have not yet provided us information about your business.</p>
        <p><%= link_to "Add your business now!", new_owner_business_path(@owner) %></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% else %>
    <div class="panel panel-danger">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <b>Services Information</b>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
      <p>
       Ok.  Your business is created.   We're about to add customers, which is kind of why you're here.  But, before we can do that, we need to know what types of services you provide them when they are with you.  You've already categorized your business when you created it.  Similar businesses who have already populated their services will be available options for you when you add here.  You can always add more, but we want you to start by adding at least one service now.  Please tell us what types of services your business provides.
       </p>
       <p><%= link_to "Add a service your business provides now!", '#' %></p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="panel panel-danger">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <b>Customer Information</b>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">
        <p>
          You have not yet added any customers.
        </p>
        <p><%= link_to "Add a customer for your business now!", new_business_customer_path(@business) %></p>
      </div>
    </div>
  <% end %>

  </div>

</div>
```

**The cucumber test itself.  It fails on step three.**

```
Feature: Business creates customers
    In order to conduct business
    my business should be able to add customers
    I can create as an owner of the business

    Background: Logging in with a business
        Given I am logged in
      And I am at my owner profile page
      And I have created one business

      Scenario: Creating first customer
        Then I expect to see content "Customer Information"
        And I expect to see content "You have not yet added any customers."
        And I expect to see a link to "Add a customer for your business now!"
        When I click the "Add a customer for your business now!" link
        Then I am at the create new customer page
        And I expect to see a form to add customer information
        And I expect to see the title "Create a customer"
        When I fill in "First name" with "Kathy"
        And I fill in "Middle name" with ""
        And I fill in "Last name" with "Davis"
        And I fill in "Email" with "test@test.com"
        And I fill in "Phone number" with "651.555.1212"
        And I fill in "Referred by" with ""
        When I click the "Save Customer" button
        Then I expect to see content "This customer has been created."
        And I am at my owner profile page
        Then I expect to see content "Customer Information"
        But I expect to not see content "You have not yet added any customers."
        Then I expect to see a link to "Customers"
        And I expect to see a link to "Add"
        And I expect to see content "Customers = 1"
        And I expect to see a link to "Add customers"
```

**Customers_controller.rb -- The definition in this won't get a :business_id passed from the previous page because it's the Owner show page and I'm pushing @business to Owner.  I think this may be my problem.**

```
class CustomersController < ApplicationController
    before_action :get_business_and_owner

    def new
        @customer = Customer.new
    end

    private

            def get_business_and_owner
                @business = Business.find(params[:business_id])
                @owner = @business.owner
            end

end
```

**owners_controller.rb -- Here I have a special method in the Owners model for "selected_business" to get the business that has the selected boolean picked.   So it does know it's business ID, but can't pass the business_id IN the test, but can in reality.**

```
class OwnersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_owner, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :set_business, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  load_and_authorize_resource


    def show
    end



    private
    def owner_params
      params.require(:owner).permit(:first_name, :last_name, :middle_name, :email, :password, :password_confirmation)
    end

        def set_owner
            @owner = Owner.find(params[:id])
        end 

        def set_business
            @business = @owner.selected_business
        end

end
```

I can put more in, but I think these are the ones.   I'm pretty sure I'm just not doing something entirely right in the step definition above.   In that I do the following code.

```
def create_business
  @business = @owner.businesses.create(name: "My Great Business", description: "Cool business, huh?")
end
```

Then I visit root.  And I'm pretty sure I just need to find a way to identify the selected business in this test in some way.   But writing a selected business method doesn't seem to work there.   Just driving me nuts so any  help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

As suspected, the problem was I'm a noob :).

In the test, I didn't actually test the flow of the application.   I logged in, and arrived at the owner profile page, as expected.   Then my create step write a business into the database, which worked great, but didn't tell the application anything so the view logic wouldn't have changed.   Thus, nothing was being passed in the test, though I could see it passed in the view.

I tried to fix this by expecting the current page to be X page, but, that also was trying to force an @variable for the business that didn't exist in the test based on how I'd written the test.   Once I remembered to let the application do the work things worked as anticipated.

I see this was voted down a couple times, so I apologize if this was too noob a question.   I'd appreciate any feedback people have when they do vote down so I can learn better.   Thanks all.